# Is there a way to run my process at a higher priority with user's permission?

Tags: c++, windows, process, thread-priority

Is there any way at all that my process's priority can be set to, say, `above normal` on Windows in a C/C++ application? If it takes an administrator privilege prompt, then fine, if it takes even more prompts, then fine, but my application runs noticeably better when at `above normal` or higher and I'd less tech-savvy users to be able to run it that way.

Edit: it should be noted it's multi-threaded, and that probably has something to do with why it runs better on `above normal` (or better yet, `high`).

Comment: See [`SetPriorityClass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219.aspx) and [`SetThreadPriority()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277.aspx)

Comment: Process by itself does not have any priority. Every thread in the process runs with its own priority.

Comment: This would be really rude to do. Even performance sensitive appliations refrain from doing this because you risk crippling the system with run-away application code.

Comment: If your CPU is fast enough, priority doesn't really matter. Priority decides which process/thread loses when your CPU is too slow. So it's not that your program runs better, it means another program runs worse.

Comment: @tadman Then what should I do to increase multi threading performance?

Comment: If this is to increase performance, then being a jerk and monopolizing the system with sub-optimal code is the worst possible solution. You need to work on making your code more efficient. Normally that means a different algorithmic approach to the problem. You need to be more specific about what you're doing. Is it possible to use the GPU to offload some compute? Is there a better approach to your computational problem? Are you using the right containers for data storage?